# how to make a file to force download in dropbox sdk

Tags: php, dropbox

I am using dropbox php sdk and i want to download the file through the browser . I have a file preview link But away to understand how can i download the file . I am using the function

```
function GetLink($dropbox_file, $preview=true, $short=true, &$expires=null)
    {
        if(is_object($dropbox_file) && !empty($dropbox_file->path)) $dropbox_file = $dropbox_file->path;
        $url = $this->apiCall(($preview?"shares":"media")."/$this->rootPath/$dropbox_file", "POST", array('locale' => null, 'short_url'=> $preview ? $short : null));
        $expires = strtotime($url->expires);
        return $url->url;
    }
```

and this is producing a link to preview the file like https://db.tt/S3znA2kE and if i open this link it becomes https://www.dropbox.com/s/64h549xaofsm67p/readme.txt
i know file can download if i will pass ?dl=1 but can't understand HOW

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082575/how-to-find-the-final-destination-url-of-an-ad-programmatically

Comment: thanx #Naing Lin Aung it works

Comment: OK, I will post it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You could stop passing "true" in the `short` parameter and thus get a long URL to start with. Then you can just use the `dl=1` parameter directly.
2. If, for some reason, you need to get a short URL, you could then expand it by doing an HTTP HEAD and looking at the returned `Location` header. E.g. (using `curl`):

   ```
   $ curl -I https://db.tt/S3znA2kE
   HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
   Server: nginx
   Date: Thu, 07 Aug 2014 21:16:19 GMT
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Connection: keep-alive
   location: https://www.dropbox.com/s/64h549xaofsm67p/readme.txt
   pragma: no-cache
   cache-control: no-cache
   ```

   After you have the full expanded URL, you can modify it to use the `dl=1` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Then you might need to crawl actual url using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082575/how-to-find-the-final-destination-url-of-an-ad-programmatically) example or I think you can grab content and point within DOM and swing back to url.

Comment: I don't have the url like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/64h549xaofsm67p/readme.txt

I have this one  https://db.tt/S3znA2kE how can i put ?dl=1 in end ot this url this is my question