# Can you force file download with the Dropbox API?

Tags: php, dropbox

I'm trying to build a basic web application using the Dropbox API. I have the file upload/folder listing etc. working but cannot find in the documentation how to force the file to download to the user's browser.  Is this possible?

If it is can someone point me in the right direction?  I'm using the standard PHP SDK.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make a file to force download in dropbox sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180080/how-to-make-a-file-to-force-download-in-dropbox-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dropbox.com: How do I force a file to download from the web](https://www.dropbox.com/help/201)

> Force a file or folder to download
>
> To cause the browser to download a file or folder rather than display
>   it, you can use dl=1 as a query parameter in your URL. For example:
>
> https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmocfrco2t0d28o/Fluffbeast.docx?dl=1 Note
>   that the original share link URL may contain query string parameters
>   already (e.g. dl=0), so app developers should make sure to properly
>   parse the URL and add or modify parameters as needed.

And if that doesn't suffice you can check [Wikihow: How to Force a File to Download from the Web on Dropbox](http://www.wikihow.com/Force-a-File-to-Download-from-the-Web-on-Dropbox), with nice screenshots.

If this is not what you had in mind you have clarified that in your question. You still can do that now.

Comment: Thanks that example works I just need to create that link for my files. Cheers ian